# Store reference to library object in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, easeljs

I have an object that I've created from the easelJS library that I'd like to store in an object.  I'm not certain whether I'm storing it or accessing it incorrectly but the object is undefined when I check it later.

An example of my object is:

```
var ShapeObject = function() {
    var self          = this;

    var name;
    var shape;
    var rotation;
    var color;

    this.initialize = function(n, s) {
        name = n;
        shape = s;
        rotation = this.randomRange()+1; 
        color = this.randomColor();
    };    
};
```

I am attempting to create and store as follows:

```
shapes = new Array();
for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    var theShape = new createjs.Shape();

    sObject = new ShapeObject();
    sObject.initialize("shape"+i, theShape);
    shapes.push(sObject);
}
```

Later I am simply attempting to deference and create as follows:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    stage.addChild(shapes[i].shape);
}
```

Is it possible to do what I am attempting?

Comment: `shape`, `name` and others are variables within the function scope, they aren't part of the created object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `shapeObject` in your code does not have a `.shape` property so `shapes[i].shape` will be `undefined`.

Local variables declared in a constructor are NOT visible properties to the outside world.  They are not properties at all, just local variables.  They are in scope for the `.initialize()` method and for your constructor, but not for anything else.

Public properties of an object must be initialized in a method by setting `this.shape = xxx` where `this` points to your object.

You can do that by changing your `initialize()` method to this:

```
this.initialize = function(n, s) {
    this.name = n;
    this.shape = s;
    this.rotation = this.randomRange()+1; 
    this.color = this.randomColor();
};
```

And, then remove all the `var` declarations by the same name as those properties.

Comment: Very simple but extremely useful.  I've just started exploring Javascript so appreciate your answer.  I will investigate this concept more.